# Can't Implement Method in Subnamespace For Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

Dotnet dev with embedded C experience here moving into cpp land to give you an idea of my experience/knowledge.

I've got a base class `Window` in `src/Core/Window/`:

```cpp
namespace Pyrite::Core::Window
{
    class PYR_API Window
    {
    public:
        using EventCallbackFn = std::function<void(Pyrite::Event&)>;

        virtual ~Window();
        virtual void OnUpdate();

        virtual uint32_t GetWidth() const = 0;
        virtual uint32_t GetHeight() const = 0;

        virtual void SetEventCallback(const EventCallbackFn& callback) = 0;
        virtual void SetVSync(bool isEnabled) = 0;
        virtual bool IsVSyncEnabled() const = 0;

        static Window* Create(const WindowProperties& props = WindowProperties());
    };
}
```

From this, I have created a derived class for the platform-specific `WindowsWindow`, I want to store this in `src/Core/Window/Platform/`:

```cpp
namespace Pyrite::Core::Window::Platform
{
    class WindowsWindow : public Pyrite::Core::Window::Window
    {
    public:
        WindowsWindow(const WindowProperties& properties);
        virtual ~WindowsWindow();

        void OnUpdate() override;

        inline uint32_t GetWidth() const override { return m_Data.Width;    }
        inline uint32_t GetHeight() const override { return m_Data.Height; }

        inline void SetEventCallback(const EventCallbackFn& callback) override { m_Data.EventCallback = callback; }
        void SetVSync(bool isEnabled) override { m_Data.VSyncEnabled = isEnabled; }
        bool IsVSyncEnabled() override {return m_Data.VSyncEnabled; }
    private:

        virtual void Init(const WindowProperties& properties);
        virtual void Close();

        GLFWwindow* m_Window;

        struct WindowData
        {
            std::string Title;
            uint32_t Width, Height;
            bool VSyncEnabled;

            EventCallbackFn EventCallback;
        };

        WindowData m_Data;

    };
}
```

However, in `WindowsWindow.cpp`, when I try to create my implementation for `Window::Create()` I get an error about not being able to define it here:

```cpp
namespace Pyrite::Core::Window::Platform
{
    static bool s_GLFWInitialised = false;
        
    Window* Window::Create(const WindowProperties& properties)
    {
        return new WindowsWindow(properties);
    }
}
```

```
'Pyrite::Core::Window::Window *Pyrite::Core::Window::Window::Create(const Pyrite::Core::Window::WindowProperties &)': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'Platform'  PyriteEngine    C:\repos\Pyrite\PyriteEngine\src\Core\Window\Platform\WIndowsWindow.cpp 9
```

When I adjust the namespaces so they're all sat in `Pyrite::Core::Window` it seems to go away... However, it seems odd to me that I can't define this in the subnamespace. I want my namespaces to follow my folder structure if possible (as that's pretty much what I'm used to and it keeps things logical and uncluttered) and hiding the platform specific stuff away in a subnamespace seems to make sense to me.

Is this just something I flat out can't do or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd appreciate some clarity on why this has a close vote... As far as I can tell, this is a well formed question with a clear issue, steps I've tried and what I'm hoping to achieve

Comment: Close vote is mine. I attempted to reproduce with the given code and had to make too many changes to the given code while winnowing down the unrelated compiler errors. I still had 17 errors when I gave up, voted to close, and moved on. Odds were too good that by the time I had the non-essential problems worked out, I'd have either accidentally fixed the problem you're seeking assistance on or accidentally removed the code that caused it while resolving something else. I recommend constructing a [mre].

Comment: But taking another kick at the can I produced https://godbolt.org/z/1eqGKxYaT which I believe faithfully reproduces your issue.

Comment: And I think the problem is `Pyrite::Core::Window` is the correct enclosing namespace, not `Pyrite::Core::Window::Platform`. But by this point I've hacked up so much code that I could be dead wrong. And if I am right, I suspect you know this already and are asking, "Why is this?" Yep. I'm pretty sure that's your question.

Comment: @user4581301 I've got the extra subnamespace to match my folder structure... Thanks for taking the time to explain the close vote and yeah, that's probably fair, I was thinking it might be something so obvious to someone with experience that I didn't need and MRE... I have, however, found a solution (I think) with the help of someone on Discord and I think you've come to the same conclusion, I just need to wrap `Window::Create` in the same namespace as the base class and have the rest of the implementations in the platform namespace (I think)

Comment: It seems to compile anyway... I'm happy to write this up as an answer or I'm happy to leave it to you since you've gone to all this effort with the MRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the separation between source files and namespaces in C++ is a feature in that they *can* follow the same structure if appropriate but other organizations are also possible.  Beyond that, it’s **impossible** to do (literally) what you ask, because it produces weird **“siblings”** for name lookup that are considered to be more trouble than they’re worth.  In particular, given

```
namespace A {
  int i;
  struct X {void f(); void g(); void h();};
  namespace B {
    void g();
    namespace C {
      int i;
      void h();
      void X::f() {g(); h(); ++i;}  // pretend this is OK
    }
  }
}
```

it’s not entirely clear whether `B::g` and/or `C::h` are “closer” to the definition of `X::f` than `X::g` or `X::h`.  It’s also not clear that it’s desirable to have moving `X::f`’s definition into or out of the class change which `i` is found.

You can often use *using-declaration*s to work around these limitations: `X` above might be defined in `B` but then **exposed** in `A` (or in `C`!).  Sometimes the affected member functions can alternatively be moved into a **base** class that belongs to a different namespace.